# How do I show/hide certain options in my select field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am trying to get my website public as soon as possible for freelancing. However I don't know how to script. I know not many are aware of this site called Webflow (translates your design into coding, instead of vice versa when web designing/building) but I am using that. The site is not equipped with the ability to change the form select to show/hide the options, depending on what the viewer selects.

For those who DOES use webflow, **[here](https://preview.webflow.com/preview/shaneinvasion-commission?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=shaneinvasion-commission&preview=17473c773b090b237f23f709bd1785be&mode=preview)** is a read-only preview. scroll own to "Contact me" for the selection I want to script.

Selection option I have when you expand it are

- select one
- Ask a question
- For ask a question, I have a hidden textbox that I want it to show
  when you select "Ask a question"
- Order a commission
- For ordering a commission, I want the textbox And the submit button
  to be hidden

IDs and value for each Form Field Id: selection

- "Select one... - value 0"
- "Ask a question - value 1"
- "Order a commission - value 2"

Textbox Id: textbox-Q value: q-box

Commission Id: Commission-button Value: 4

submit-button Id: submit-form Value: 5

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery solution for you, so you'll need to include the jQuery library in your code to make use of it (jQuery is easy to learn for juniors: www.jquery.com)

I won't call this code my sistine chapel, but it gets the job done.

```js
function hideDynamicFields() {
  $('#dynamic-fields').children().hide();
}

$('#service').on('change', function(){
  hideDynamicFields();
  var choice = $(this).val();
  if(choice == 'question') {
    $('input[name=question]').show();
  } else if(choice =='commission') {
    $('textarea[name=commission]').show();
  }
});
```

```css
#dynamic-fields input,
#dynamic-fields textarea {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="service">
  <option></option>
  <option value="question">Ask a question</option>
  <option value="commission">Order a Commission </option>
</select>
<div id="dynamic-fields">
  <input type="text" name="question" />
  <textarea name="commission"></textarea>
</div>
```